# Looking for easygoing, well-motivated introductions to matrix norms.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I find all the various [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) very hard to navigate, probably because I don't know what they're used for.

> **Question.** What are some easygoing, well-motivated introductions to matrix norms? Motivation is key here: I want something that goes out of its way to explain what the purpose or "use" of each norm is.

Comment: Induced norms are perhaps of interest here.

Comment: So I'm not sure how much this helps you, but [here is an old answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394515/81360) where I say what the matrix norms are and what they do.  The induced norms are well-motivated in any functional analysis textbook, I believe.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks.