# Properties of entrywise L1 matrix norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Consider the entrywise $L_1$ norm on matrices, given by

$$\|M\|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |M_{i,j}|.$$

I'm looking for useful properties this norm might have.  Is there anything we can say about $\|A \cdot B \|_1$, in terms of the matrices $A,B$? (e.g., upper-bound $\|A \cdot B\|_1$, based on some quantities about $A$ and $B$?)

Answer (score 8):

$$ \| AB \|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |(AB)_{ij}| \le \sum_{i,j,k} |A_{ik}| |B_{kj}| \le \sum_{i,j,k,l} |A_{ik}| |B_{lj}| = \|A\|_1 \|B\|_1 $$

Answer (score 0):

The following property holds for most matrix norms as long as $A$ and $B$ are square
$$||AB||\leq||A||\cdot||B||$$
If the matrices are not square, then this submultiplicative property still holds for any vector-induced matrix norm.

Comment: This is not a vector-induced matrix norm.