# 1 norm $\|\|_1$, of non square matrix

Tags: matrix-norms

Does $1$ norm exist for non-square matrices? By $1$ norm I mean

$d (x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x^i-y^i|, x=(x_1,\dots, x_n), y=(y_1,\dots, y_n)$

Suppose $A$ is $m\times n, (m\ne n)$ matrix what can we say about $\|A\|_1$? Also, can we say  $\|A\|_1=\|A^T\|_1= \|A^TA\|_1=\|AA^T\|_1$? and $\|AB\|_1\le \|A\|_1\|B\|_1$ Thanks for helping.

Comment: What property of the norm are you uncertain about $d$ satisfying?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I don't understand what are you talking about, if possible give an example and explain.

Comment: Cannot do so in a comment.  If this fails to be clear I am forced to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem to define an *"entrywise" matrix norm* defined as follows: 
$$
\|A\|_1=\|vec(A)\|_1=\sum_{i,j}|A_{i,j}|
$$
see [wikipedia, Matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). It is a norm and the induced distance is (if $A$, $B$ have same dimensions):
$$
d(A,B)=\sum_{i,j}|A_{i,j}-B_{i,j}|
$$
This norm is a sub-multiplicative norm (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2328869/450342)):
$$
\|AB\|_1\leq\|A\|_1\|B\|_1
$$
but, **attention**, in general:
$$
\|A^tA\|_1\neq\|AA^t\|_1
$$

Another example of "entrywise" matrix norm often encountered in practice is the Frobenius norm. This norm is defined as follows:

$$
\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\text{tr}(A^tA)}=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|A_{i,j}|^2}
$$
Frobenius norm also fulfills the sub-multiplicative property (Cauchy-Schwarz in action, see 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393301/frobenius-norm-of-product-of-matrix)):
$$
\|AB\|_F\leq \|A\|_F\|B\|_F
$$

Compared to the previous case $\|.\|_1$, like we have $\text{tr}(A^tA)=\text{tr}(AA^t)$, Frobenius norm also fulfills the property:

$$
\|AA^t\|_F=\|A^tA\|_F
$$

---

To be complete one must also say a word about *Matrix norms induced by vector norms*. One can define:
$$
\|A\|_1=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}
$$
(**attention** despite identical the notation, this norm is different from the previously defined $\|vec(.)\|_1 $, here we have $\|A\|_1=\max_j \sum_i|A_{i,j}|$)

An immediate generalization, valid for any $1\leq p \leq \infty$, is:
$$
\|A\|_p=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}
$$

Such norms are called *Matrix norms induced by vector norms*, they automatically fulfill the sub-multiplicative property: 
$$
\|AB\|_p \leq \|A\|_p \|B\|_p 
$$

**Attention:** however in general, 
$$
\|AA^t\|_p \neq \|A^tA\|_p
$$

---

Also note this important fact, as we are in **finite** dimension all these previously defined matrix norms are **equivalent** in the sense that for any two matrix norm $\|.\|_\alpha$ and $\|.\|_\beta$ it exists $r$ and $s$ such that:
$$
\forall A,\ r\|A\|_\alpha\leq \|A\|_\beta \leq s\|A\|_\alpha
$$
in peculiar if a sequence $n\rightarrow (A)_n$ is convergent for a given matrix norm it is also convergent for all the other norms.