# Is there a way to measure the "magnitude" of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

First in the case of unitary matrix $U^*=U^{-1}$. and $\det U=1$.

See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

However, notice $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0.1&0.1\\
0.1&0.1\\
\end{pmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
10&10\\
10&10\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}B^n=\begin{pmatrix}
\infty&\infty\\
\infty&\infty\\
\end{pmatrix}$,
where $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}U^n$ was still a unitary matrix.

Obviously, $A$ converge to $0$ and $B$ blow up.
In the sense that $|B|>|U|$ and $|U|>|A|$.

My question was that, is there any way to measure the magnitude of a matrix?
(Notice $\det A=\det B=0$)

Comment: I give a brief explanation of  how matrix norms work [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394113/what-are-some-usual-norms-for-matrices/1394515#1394515)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you. I had an other example. Consider a matrix 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1.01&0\\
0&0.1
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0.99&0\\
0&0.99
\end{pmatrix}$. Then if we set the norm to be $(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2)^{1/2}$ then $||B||>||A||$ yet $A$ still blow up and $B$ converge to $0$.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Matrices).  Do you know what eigenvalues are?

Comment: It is notable that, while the particular norm you have chosen fails to capture the phenomenon as you hoped, there always exists a (multiplicative) matrix norm such that $\|A\| > 1$ if $A^n \to \infty$ and there always exists a (multiplicative) matrix norm such that $\|A\|<1$ if $A^n \to 0$

Comment: In your particular example, the spectral norm (the operator norm associated with the usual Euclidean difference) satisfies $\|A\| = 1.01$ and $\|B\| = 0.99$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) or in the case of matrices, the equivelant concept of [matrix norm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot, however, consider Consider a matrix 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1.01&0\\
0&0.1
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0.99&0\\
0&0.99
\end{pmatrix}$. Then if we set the norm to be $(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2)^{1/2}$ then $||B||>||A||$ yet $A$ still blow up and $B$ converge to $0$.