# What are some applications of norms and why study them? Is there a theory of norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I am taking a first course in numerical methods and have passed a course in Linear Algebra. I am curious to know, how norms(a mathematical abstraction of the length of a vector) come about? Are they commonplace in Physics? Do they have interesting applications other than finding limits?

Kind regards,

Quasar.

Comment: Maybe you can find answers for some questions by reading about functional analysis and related concepts as normed spaces, Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces (the Wikipedia's articles can help).

Comment: Thank you, I do surely find them cool!

Comment: You have a lot of applications of the norm in the field of Riemannian and sub - Riemannian geometry to (which depends of the "norm" defined on the space).

Comment: This doesn't completely answer your question, but in [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394515/81360) I discuss some of the ways that norms (as applied to matrices) are used in linear algebra

Comment: Norms are important not only for "finding limits", but also for saying what it is that you mean by a "limit" in the first place.  Norms are very commonplace in physics.  Specifically, norms in Hilbert spaces are often associated with the "energy" associated with a particular vector.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, cheers for sharing a very informative answer. Thinking out loud; 
I want to apply this idea to an arbitrary space. I believe, that linear differential operators with constant coefficients $D$, $(D-1)$, $(D+2)^2$ form a vector space, as they satisfy properties of ordinary polynomials. Therefore, I should be able take any function of a differential operator $D$, and show it is continuous at a point $D_0$ , if whenever $\vert \vert D - D_0 \vert \vert < \delta$, I am able to prove that $\vert \vert f(D)-f(D_0)\vert \vert < \epsilon$. The values of $f(D)$ form a continuum.

Comment: So, functions of matrices(operators) can be shown to be continuous?

Comment: @Quasar Yes, that's right. Some care needs to be taken in defining a topology on differential operators, though, since the derivative map is itself discontinuous