# How to represent the modulus of a determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, determinant, normed-spaces

We are doing high school determinants and I have a doubt regarding the symbols used to represent modulus of a matrix. 
I guessed it to be two pair of parallel lines viz. :

 **||A||** , 

where **A** is any square matrix.
But my teacher said it is wrong and instead suggested to write the modulus of a matrix in linguistic form i.e. mod det. **A** stating that ||**A**|| is used for something else. 
After exploring I found that it is indeed used to represent the norm of a vector. But what's striking is that norm is similar to modulus (as I conclude after reading a bit of wikipedia). 
[Wikipedia page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Llb.png)
**So can anyone please help me understand the relation between the norm and modulus and also whether it can be used to represent modulus of a matrix in this form ||**A**||?**
 
Thank You :)

Comment: What do you mean by "modulus of a matrix" ?

Comment: @SolubleFish From the context, it looks like it refers to the absolute value of the determinant

Comment: @SolubleFish I meant determinant. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

The notation that I would use is $|\det(\mathbf A)|$. A similar notation is typically used in the statement of the [multivariate change of variables rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) for integration, for instance.

If $\mathbf A$ is a matrix, then $\|\mathbf A\|$ typically denotes the norm of this matrix. For more information on matrix norms (in addition to the information you already found, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) Wikipedia page or my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394515/81360). Note that the function $f(\mathbf A) = |\det(\mathbf A)|$ does not fit the definition of a matrix norm (since it lacks the homogeneity property), so I would say that the notation $\|\mathbf A\|$ for this function is inappropriate.

Comment: What are the dimensions of norm?

Comment: @C I don’t understand your comment

Comment: I meant what dimensions does norm have. Or is it just a number?

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ denotes a norm, then for any matrix $A$, $\|A\|$ is a number, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle typographical difference between $||A||$ and $\|A\|$ (absolute value of the determinant vs. norm).

There was no intent in this notation, it is purely coincidental. My bet is that to define a new norm operator, doubling the bars appeared naturally.

If you write a text where you need $||A||$ to appear, you should warn the reader that this is not a norm (or use Ben's notation). An ugly alternative is $|(|A|)|$.

Comment: How to write in Ben's notation?