# Are All Submultiplicative Matrix Norms Operator Norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

By definition, an operator norm (a matrix norm induced by a vector norm) is submultiplicative.

I am wondering if the converse is true i.e. given a submultiplicative matrix norm, is there a vector norm which induces it?

Thank you!

Comment: Frobenius. ${}$

Comment: The [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) is a known example of a submultiplicative norm that is not an operator norm: for all operator norms, $|||I|||$ must be equal to $1$, but for the Frobenius norm $||.||_F$ we have $||I||_F = \sqrt{n}$ if $n$ is the dimension.

Comment: You could also try the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @AnneBauval I was just joking, I mentioned the Frobenius norm in the first comment and it was repeated in the next, so I decided to go for a trifecta.

Comment: But what about the Frobenius norm?

Comment: @user See also my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394113/what-are-some-usual-norms-for-matrices/1394515#1394515) for some other examples, including most of the Ky-Fan and Schatten norms.